# How to prevent Buffer overflow with segmentation or paging?

Tags: c, buffer, overflow, paging

How do you make use of segmentation and paging to prevent buffer overflow?
One guess might be - because segmentation only gives a portion of memory to each process and if the process tried to access an address outside its segment then a segfault will occur. Please tell me if that is correct or not.
Thank you!

Comment: You prevent buffer overflow by having your code not overwrite the ends of a buffer.  Segmentation/paging cannot fix your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segmentation / paging will not prevent your code from *attempting* to access memory outside of its boundaries. That is the definition of a buffer overflow, and no sort of memory protections will attempt broken code from attempting to do things it is not allowed to do.

What segmentation or paging can do, is prevent your code from *successfully* accessing memory it doesn't own.  The only option an operating system really has is to kill a process that the hardware has detected attempting to do something "bad".

Comment: In most cases this won't be useful, but the operating system typically sends a message to the process (a signal in *nix systems) which the process could intercept and deal with; it's the failure to intercept the signal that causes the process to be terminated, not the invalid memory access itself. A process that can control memory page tables could theoretically recover well, and a process that makes proper use of setjmp/longjmp might also recover, but as I started with, these are rare situations.